# Determine if the action was "Build" or "Build and Run" in XCode?

Tags: xcode, build, project

I have a custom application which requires a bunch of things to be set up before it is run. I want to add it as a build phase so I can use it when I do "Build and Run" but not when I do "Build". **How do I check it in a shell script which is *run* as a *build phase* at the end?**

*Please don't ask why*

Comment: Why can't you just do the setup every time?

Comment: I can. But that way it would be quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if there is something special triggered for "Build" vs "Build and Run". You might want to check out a different build configuration. Projects come with a Debug and a Build configuration, maybe add a "Config&Build" that has some flags set. If the flag is set then do your setup stuff. Then it would be easy enough to switch configurations. I do something similar with my debug output and only turning them on in the debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even have a Mac, so this is purely my imagination. I assume, XCode allows you to specify which executable to run when "Build and Run" is used. If so, you can write a simple batch file, which will perform all the required setup and then run your main app. Point XCode to that file and you're fine.